What is a list of Korean words that contain the "UR" sound from the English word "URN"? What is the hangul symbol or glyph for the R-Colored Vowel?
What are examples of common Korean words that contain an "urrrr" sound or an "errr" sound?
The following is a table of English words that contain the R-Colored Vowel



English SoundandEnglish Spelling
English SoundandInternationalPhoneticAlphabetNotation
English SoundwithPhonetic Notation Based UponCommon Mispellingsmade byYoung Students
Korean SoundandEnglish Spelling
Korean SoundwithKorean Spelling




URN
/ɝn/
UhRN
OhNGee
옹기


FERN
/fɝn/
FurN
EeAwngChEerEeOo
양치류


LEARN
/lɝn/
LurN
PAwEhEeOoDAw
배우다




What are some examples of some of the most commonly used Korean words that contain a sound that is similar to the R-Colored Vowel?

The "r" in those words is usually left out in Korean transliteration for the same reasons I mentioned in my answer to one of your other questions.
All three you listed are not used in Korean as far as I know, but you can see similar examples in words like 턴 (turn) and 워닝 (warning) which are listed in korean dictionaries.
The transliteration is following British pronunciation which almost drops the r sound in those words.  If you were to include the r sound, you would have to spell them like 터른 and 워르닝, which sound much worse. 턴 and 워닝 seem much more sensible.
It doesn't mean that all such r's are dropped though.  Names like Corsica and Marcel are transliterated with the r syllable in them, like 코르시카 and 마르셀.  These are non-English names, but I believe there are similar cases even for English words.
